# How to find multiple zeroes of a single function

Tags: list-manipulation, equation-solving

This is the problem I am solving.
[image]

I have defined my wanted equation as it is shown on the picture. Finding the first 0 (root) is not difficult with using FindRoot function.
The problem that i am facing is following:

What is the simplest way to find, for instance, first 10 Roots using FindRoot function?

Comment: Can you give the numerical values used for the `Plot` and `FindRoot`? Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Please post copy & paste-able code (`InputForm`) rather than images. Code should include all data (e.g., numeric values of parameters) needed to reproduce the problem.

Comment: You can get a pretty good approximation of the zeros by replacing $J_0(x)\to\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi x}}\cos(x-\pi/4)$ and $Y_0(x)\to\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi x}}\sin(x-\pi/4)$ and solving the resulting trigonometric equation analytically. Then, if needed, you can use these approximate zeros as starting points for numerical root finding.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

equation[s1_] = C1/D1 BesselJ[0, s1 c] + D1/D1 BesselY[0, s1 c];

c = 1/300; C1 = 1; D1 = 1;
```

With [`Solve`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Solve.html) or [`NSolve`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NSolve.html) or [`Reduce`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Reduce.html), include a constraint on the range of `s1`. Since you are plotting on the interval `{0, 15000}`, use the constraint `0 <= s1 <= 15000`

```
(roots = Solve[{equation[s1] == 0, 0 <= s1 <= 15000}, s1, Reals]) // N

(* Solve::incs: Warning: Solve was unable to prove that the solution set found is complete.

{{s1 -> 69.0992}, {s1 -> 953.787}, {s1 -> 1890.83}, {s1 -> 2831.38}, {s1 -> 
   3772.88}, {s1 -> 4714.77}, {s1 -> 5656.85}, {s1 -> 6599.05}, {s1 -> 
   7541.31}, {s1 -> 8483.63}, {s1 -> 9425.97}, {s1 -> 10368.3}, {s1 -> 
   11310.7}, {s1 -> 12253.1}, {s1 -> 13195.5}, {s1 -> 14138.}} *)
```

With exact input, the roots are exact

```
equation[s1] /. roots // FullSimplify

(* {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0} *)
```

Or numerically,

```
equation[s1] /. N[roots, 20]

(* {0.*10^-20, 0.*10^-19, 0.*10^-18, 0.*10^-21, 0.*10^-21, 0.*10^-21, 0.*10^-21, 
 0.*10^-20, 0.*10^-20, 0.*10^-20, 0.*10^-20, 0.*10^-20, 0.*10^-20, 0.*10^-20, 
 0.*10^-20, 0.*10^-20} *)
```

Graphically,

```
Plot[equation[s1], {s1, 0, 15000}, Frame -> True,
 Epilog -> {Red, AbsolutePointSize[4],
   Point[{s1, 0} /. roots]}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, it works, it just takes some time to calculate.

Comment: `Solve` was used to show how to get exact solutions. If exact solutions aren't needed, `NSolve` is faster. However, to ensure that you get all of the roots with `NSolve`, you need to use arbitrary-precision by specifying a `WorkingPrecision`. For example, `NSolve[{equation[s1] == 0, 0 <= s1 <= 15000}, s1, Reals, WorkingPrecision -> 20]`